# Is "on my way" an adverbial complement?

Tags: idioms

> “I’m on my way home.” (John Steinbeck, East of Eden)

Is *on my way* an adverbial complement; *home* modifying *on my way*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. "I'm on my way" is a direct idiom meaning "I am (currently) travelling". It derives from "way" meaning "path", and thus originally meant "I am on the path [towards] home".

"I'm on my way home" therefore means "I am currently travelling [to my] home".

The following is a valid exchange:

> 1. Can you come home early? Jill fell over in the park!
> 2. On my way

Note you might also find this idiom via the Internet abbreviation *omw*.